# Getiing response in improper JSON format from spring Controller using @ResponseBody

Tags: json, rest, jackson-databind

My request method :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/select",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public AppDto getChildRecords(@RequestBody ChildModel model) {
        oAppDto = new AppDto();

        DbService oDbService = new DbService();
        oDbService.getChildRecords(oAp[enter image description here][1]pDto,model);
        return oAppDto;
    }
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>child-record-api</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest-api</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest-api</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.tcs.poc.blockchain.dummy.cors.filter.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Response :-

{
    "status": "200",
    "message": "Success",
    "data": "{\r\n  \"ch_id\" : \"07vj0L7n1h\",\r\n  \"name\" : \"Srijib Sen\",\r\n  \"m_name\" : \"K Sen\",\r\n  \"f_name\" : \"D Sen\",\r\n  \"address\" : \"Kharagpur\",\r\n  \"dob\" : \"15/05/1992\"\r\n}"
}

Due to \r\n elements of the JSON are not accessible.

My AppDto class :-

```
package com.tcs.poc.blockchain.dummy.dto.app;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class AppDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1783128529410215201L;

    private String status;

    private String message;

    private Object data;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPkwz.gif)

Comment: `\r\n` are just escapes for end of line markers (\r = 0x0d = CR, \n = 0x0a = LF). Quotation marks `"` are also escaped. This happens inside "data", so whatever is responsible for serializing "data" in `AppDto` (you didn't show the code for that) is at fault. Find what it is, turn off escaping.

Comment: import java.io.Serializable;

public class AppDto implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = -1783128529410215201L;

 private String status; 
 private String message; 
 private Object data;

 public String getStatus() {
  return status;
 }
 public void setStatus(String status) {
  this.status = status;
 }
 public String getMessage() {
  return message;
 }
 public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
 }
 public Object getData() {
  return data;
 }
 public void setData(Object data) {
  this.data = data;
 } 
}

Comment: This is my AppDto class

Comment: Please edit the question; comments are not meant to be permanent. Try using a proper POJO, or possibly a Map etc. if you need to be general, instead of `Object`. I suspect Object just serializes via the `toString()` method, which does the escaping, but I didn't test that. If that works: you can answer your own question, and accept the answer.